# Get the number of clients connected to an RMI service

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I have a `Remote` service exported via RMI. Can I get the number of clients connected to this service?

I'd strongly prefer a native method (counting sockets) over building my own solution where clients need to register themselves, since I need this for error detection and the native solution would be least error prone.

Getting the exact number of clients would be nice, but mostly I'm just interested in knowing whether it's 0 or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as the 'number of clients connected to an RMI service', because there is no such state as 'connected to an RMI service'. RMI doesn't have explicit connections. It has underlying, secret TCP connections, but they are transient in nature.

You can count distinct incoming `RemoteServer.getClientHost()` values, but you are then assuming that hosts = clients, and you still have no way of knowing when a client has called you for the last time. Unless your application knows, in which case it is a matter of counting them yourself, e.g. at the login and logout steps or whatever corresponds to that in your application.

Comment: But maybe there's a secret way to count the secret connection?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom Even if there was, which there isn't, it isn't what you are asking for, because what you are asking for doesn't exist.